# create a really long string more efficiently than this

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, object, switch-statement

so, I am pretty new to this game, and am trying to understand javaScript way better than I currently do. I have this block of code, if it is too long to read, then just skip to my question at the bottom...

```
    function createCSSRule(selectorName, necessaryProperties){
    //add class to control all divs
    var propertyNameBases, propertyPrefixes, propertyValues, propertySuffixes;
    var cssString = selectorName + "{\n";
    for (var i9 = 0; i9 < necessaryProperties.length; ++i9){
        switch (selectorName){
            case "."+options.allPictures:
                switch(necessaryProperties[i9]){
                    case "position":
                        propertyNameBases = ["position"];
                        propertyPrefixes    = [""],
                        propertyValues      = ["absolute"],
                        propertySuffixes    = [""];
                        break;
                    case "height":
                        propertyNameBases = ["height"];
                        propertyPrefixes    = [""],
                        propertyValues      = ["100%"],
                        propertySuffixes    = [""];
                        break;
                    case "width":
                        propertyNameBases = ["width"];
                        propertyPrefixes    = [""],
                        propertyValues      = ["100%"],
                        propertySuffixes    = [""];
                        break;
                    case "background":
                        propertyNameBases = ["background"];
                        propertyPrefixes    = [""],
                        propertyValues      = ["scroll","#fff","50% 50%","no-repeat","cover"],
                        propertySuffixes    = ["-attachment","-color","-position","-repeat","-size"];
                        break;
                    case "transform":
                        propertyNameBases   = ["transform"],
                        propertyPrefixes    = ["", "-moz-", "-webkit-"],
                        propertyValues      = [options.threeDOrigin,options.threeDStyle,"translate3d("+options.translate3dpx+")"],
                        propertySuffixes    = ["-origin","-style",""];
                        break;
                    case "transition":
                        propertyNameBases = ["transition"],
                        propertyPrefixes    = ["", "-webkit-"],
                        propertyValues      = [options.transitionLength + "ms", options.transitionPath, "all"],
                        propertySuffixes    = ["-duration","-timing-function","-property"]; //-delay"];                 
                        break;
                    default:
                        console.log("missing");
                        propertyNameBases   = null;
                        propertyPrefixes    = null;
                        propertyValues      = null;
                        propertySuffixes    = null;
                        break;
                }
                break;
        case "."+options.currentPic:
            switch(necessaryProperties[i9]){
                    case "transform":
                        propertyNameBases   = ["transform"],
                        propertyPrefixes    = ["", "-moz-", "-webkit-"],
                        propertyValues      = [options.threeDOrigin,"translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px)"],
                        propertySuffixes    = ["-origin",""];
                        break;
                    default:
                        console.log("missing");
                        propertyNameBases   = null;
                        propertyPrefixes    = null;
                        propertyValues      = null;
                        propertySuffixes    = null;
                        break;
                }
                break;
        case "."+options.currentPic+"."+options.picAfterCurrent:
            switch(necessaryProperties[i9]){
                    case "transform":
                        propertyNameBases   = ["transform"],
                        propertyPrefixes    = ["", "-moz-", "-webkit-"],
                        propertyValues      = [options.threeDOrigin,"translate3d("+options.negativeTranslate3dpx+")"],
                        propertySuffixes    = ["-origin",""];
                        break;
                    default:
                        console.log("missing");
                        propertyNameBases   = null;
                        propertyPrefixes    = null;
                        propertyValues      = null;
                        propertySuffixes    = null;
                        break;
                }
                break;
            default:
                console.log("wait a second");
                break;
        }
        //name the selector
        //iterate through properties
        for (i10 = 0; i10 < propertyNameBases.length; i10++){
            //iterate through suffixes and value pairs
            for (var i11 = 0; i11 < propertyValues.length; i11++){
                //iterate through prefixes
                if(propertyValues !== false){
                    for (var i12 = 0; i12 < propertyPrefixes.length; i12++){
                        cssString = cssString+" "+propertyPrefixes[i12]+propertyNameBases[i10]+propertySuffixes[i11]+": "+propertyValues[i11]+";\n"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
var forAllPictures = ["position","height","width","background","transition","transform"];   
var forCurrentPic = ["transform"];
var forpicAfterCurrent = ["transform"];
createCSSRule("."+options.allPictures, forAllPictures);
createCSSRule("."+options.currentPic, forCurrentPic);
createCSSRule("."+options.currentPic+"."+options.picAfterCurrent, forpicAfterCurrent);
```

basically, what is going to happen is I am going to pass a string (which is in a combination of variables) to the first parameter, and an array to the second. The first parameter acts as my class name, and the second parameter acts as my array of necessary css properties. I have included the output below so you can get a simple understanding of what I am going for. Each array inside of the if statements is used by the i 's in each for loop to output a string.

Each switch statement sets a specific variable and then 3 for-loops take over concatenating a very long string, which happens to be the css below

```
.slideShowPics{
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background-attachment: scroll;
    background-color: #fff;
    background-position: 50% 50%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    transition-duration: 5000ms;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 5000ms;
    transition-timing-function: ease-in;
    -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-in;
    transition-property: all;
    -webkit-transition-property: all;
    transform-origin: 0% 0%;
    -moz-transform-origin: 0% 0%;
    -webkit-transform-origin: 0% 0%;
    transform-style: flat;
    -moz-transform-style: flat;
    -webkit-transform-style: flat;
    transform: translate3d(-640px, 0px, 0px);
    -moz-transform: translate3d(-640px, 0px, 0px);
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(-640px, 0px, 0px);
}
.currentSlideShowPic{
    transform-origin: 0% 0%;
    -moz-transform-origin: 0% 0%;
    -webkit-transform-origin: 0% 0%;
    transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);
    -moz-transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);
}
.currentSlideShowPic.movingOut{
    transform-origin: 0% 0%;
    -moz-transform-origin: 0% 0%;
    -webkit-transform-origin: 0% 0%;
    transform: translate3d(640px, 0px, 0px);
    -moz-transform: translate3d(640px, 0px, 0px);
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(640px, 0px, 0px);
}
```

I would love for someone to suggest an easier way to do this.

I do not feel like I am using this language correctly. If there is anyone out there who has a better idea than what I am currently using, I would love to hear it.

Like I said, I am still learning.

I feel like I should be able to do this with an object, I just have no idea what I am doing when it comes to objects. If anyone has any articles that are written in clean everyday vernacular, or at least some really good examples, I would appreciate that, otherwise your own examples/explainations would be most appreciated. If, of course, I am able to do this with an object...

Comment: Check: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/, if you want to optimize your code.

Comment: I would really like to not use less if possible since I need this as a text string. Any ideas would be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry, I couldn't really understand how the result should look like, but this is also indicative of... do not use `switch` constructs. Of course, every rule has exceptions, but really `switch` exists in JavaScript for the same reason it has special infix operators for manipulating bits of 32-bit integers (while not even having 32-bit integers to begin with). I.e. it's a dark legacy of C, where these operations made perfect sense. JavaScript was made to resemble C because of marketing considerations. Developers were thought to like C, and making a language to resemble it would make it more popular.

## Why not?

Because `switch` more often then not makes you write repetitive code that you cannot reuse.
Take for example this bit of your code:

```
case "height":
    propertyNameBases = ["height"];
    propertyPrefixes    = [""],
    propertyValues      = ["100%"],
    propertySuffixes    = [""];
    break;
case "width":
    propertyNameBases = ["width"];
    propertyPrefixes    = [""],
    propertyValues      = ["100%"],
    propertySuffixes    = [""];
    break;
```

It repeats 90% of the first block in the second. But can you reuse it, if you needed one more of these? - No.

## Then how?

Use polymorphism. It is cheap in JavaScript, it is easy to write. Here's an example of how you could reduce the verbosity of the above:

```
function rules() {
    function propertyTemplate(property) {
        return function (template, defalutValue) {
            return function (value) {
                return template.replace("%v", value || defalutValue);
            };
        }("%p:%v".replace("%p", property));
    }
    return {
        width: propertyTemplate("width", "100%"),
        height: propertyTemplate("height", "200%")
    };
}
// examples:
console.log(rules().width());
// width:100%

var text = [], ruleset = rules();
for (var rule in ruleset)
    text.push(ruleset[rule]((Math.random() * 100) | 0) + "%");
console.log(text.join(";"));
// width:47%;height:65%
```

Which is of course just an example, it's up to you to make it do what you want it to.

Comment: yeah, sorry. I have never even heard of polymorphism in javascript. please comment with a link to an awesome article... I have orielly's javascript book, so I might just crack that open too. But yeah, I was definitely not keen on using switch statements. I ended up making a multidimensional array for each code block that I wanted to create and iterating through it with 3 for statements.

Comment: @MichaelMcLaughlin you would be surprised... There are a lot of articles on polymorphism in JavaScript, but most of them come from "unreliable" sources... The tradition seems to be to associate polymorphism with prototype inheritance (which is only one way of doing it). Here's an interesting article on parametrical polymorphism: http://ericleads.com/2011/06/polymorphic-functions-and-multiple-dispatch-in-javascript/ but it's not what I had in mind either :) I've checked publications of Crochford, Eich and Horwat, but no cigar...

Comment: ... One thing I can think about: Scheme, it is conceptually very similar to JavaScript, and the description of polymorphism as given in SICP would be very useful here as well. That's about the best I can think about :)

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you may be reinventing the wheel - why not use jQuery or zeptojs, and do

$('your css selector here').css({property:value, property:value...})

Comment: I actually do need a string for this. since I am keeping it inside of a style tag which enters the dom through a document fragment. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

There is already a javascript library for doing what you're trying to accomplish. http://lesscss.org/

Personally I prefer sass-lang (not javascript) http://sass-lang.com/

As for objects then it could be as simple as this:

```
// An object with css properties
var css = {
    background: "#FF0099",
    position: "absolute",
    height: "100%",
    width: "100%"
    //etc...
};

// You could also write it as such:
var css = {};
css["background"] = "#FF0099";
css["position"]   = "absolute";
css["height"]     = "100%";
css["width"]      = "100%";

// Parse the object into valid css using a string and a for in loop
var style = '.myClass{';
for (var i in css) {
    style += i + ':' + css[i] + ';';
}
style += '}';
```

Comment: unfortunately, this kind of forces me to rewrite every object though, right?

Comment: I would really like to not use less if possible since I need this as a text string. Any other ideas would be helpful.